# Can you refreeze spring roll wrappers.

Tags: chinese-cuisine

Made spring rolls but still got loads of wrappers left, they came frozen so can I refreeze them?

Comment: Err... why not?

Comment: Yes, you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, as Robert said. Just be forwarned of condensation forming at the bottom when you thaw which will ruin the wrappers. So support with three or four layers of paper towels.